# How to access variables in the script tag outside the script

Tags: javascript, html

I need to access the value of the variable inside the script tag to a meta tag content.

This is the JS Code that i used to get the image variable

```
<script>
       var pic = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0];
       var src = pic.getAttribute('src');
       console.log(src);
</script>
```

I need to access the src tag to the content of the meta og-image

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/example/**src value should be here**" />
```

Is it possible? or else what can I do?

Comment: You can only access variables in JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Instead of trying to access the variable in the HTML, have the JavaScript update the meta tag. But this probably won't do anything useful, because applications that read meta tags may not run the JavaScript first.

Comment: As Barmar mentions, the bots that read the meta tags are unlikely to execute the JS at all. I strongly recommend moving the logic out of client-side JS and to something that runs server side or at build-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Dynamically created or modified Open Graph tags are likely not read by any of the tools that are reading them.

If you know what image you want on the server, you can set it there too

```
<?PHP
  $image = "https://example.com/example/image1.jpg";
  ?>
  ...
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?= $image ?>" />
  ...
  <img class="abc" src="<?= $image ?>"/>
```

---

In the unlikely case you can get Google to execute the JS while reading the page, you likely need to use  createElement since the meta tag will be read and the image empty if you do it after load.

So this has to be inline AFTER the image tag

```
const src = document.querySelector(".abc").src;
const meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute('property','og:image');     meta.setAttribute('content',`https://example.com/example/${src}`); 
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(meta)
```

---

Alternative with document.write

```
const src = document.querySelector(".abc").src;
document.write(`<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/example/${src}" />`);
```